# 'confirm_password' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use DRF and write registration for my blog on django. I am receiving an error with password in views.py at the following line

```
User.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Here is the view that I am using

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):    
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(), )
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return (permissions.AllowAny(), )
        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsOwner(), )

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            User.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)
            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_created)
        return Response({'status': 'Bad request', 'message': 'Account could not be created with received data'},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And here is the serializer that goes along with it

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'confirm_password',)

        def create(self, validation_data):
            return User.objects.create(**validation_data)
```

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the above code I am quite sure the problem is due to your User model does not have `confirm_password` field in it, as Django's built in User model does not have `confirm_password` field in it. So if you are using django `User` please remove `confirm_password` from the serializers it would work fine.

But if you want to use the way you are using you need to use `AbstractBaseUser` to make a custom Django user, and need your `models.py` to be modified like this.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')

        if not kwargs.get('username'):
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid username.')

        account = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), username=kwargs.get('username')
        )

        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        account = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)

        account.is_admin = True
        account.save()

        return account


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return ' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name
```

also you need to change your `settings.py` file as well, specify at the bottom.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.Account'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here that seem a bit... strange.

1. You are overriding `create` on your view and the only difference appears to be the way that you are overriding your error format. Maybe this is better left to [the exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28223235/359284)?
2. You are overriding `create` on your serializer, but it's never actually being used. This is because you are never calling `serializer.save` or `serializer.create` in your view, which is the recommended way to create a new object.
3. You are taking in the password confirmation, but you aren't actually doing anything with it. It's just sitting there for the ride, and it's not even a required field.

Now, the first two points you are going to have to deal with on your own. I would honestly recommend dropping your custom `create` methods and just overriding the error formatting on the exception handler, but in any case that's not where your current issue is.

Your current issue is coming because of #3, you are passing the confirmed password into the `create_user` method, which isn't expecting it. Either you should drop the password confirmation ([highly recommended](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/22879/21156), your API shouldn't be dealing with it) or you need to pop that field off after it is validated, so it isn't passed into whatever create method you are using.